# Query returned successfully but i dont see anyway

Tags: postgresql, select, procedure

I'm new to postgresql, i have a procedure block this is working but i dont see any table or column, what this problem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE list3(
    )
LANGUAGE sql

AS $$
select * from stok
$$;

call list3()
```

Comment: Procedures don't return anything, use a function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Functions return values.

Example:

```
create table table_example(col1 varchar(100),col2 int);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table_example() 
   RETURNS TABLE (
      l_col1 VARCHAR,
      l_col2 INT
) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY 
      SELECT *  
      FROM table_example;
END; 
$$ 

select * from get_table_example();
```